# memory leak in czmq on Windows build

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, zeromq, heap-corruption

zmq version: zeromq-4.0.3(build as Windows DLL)

czmq version: czmq-2.0.3(build as Windows DLL)

IDE: Visual Studio Professional 2010

I have a small program which creates two thread and uses ZMQ_PAIR socket over inproc to send data from one to another.
One thread sends data using zstr_send and other receives using zstr_recv. 
If I don't free string received from zstr_recv , I get constant increase of memory (via Task Manager).
If I free it using free(), i get heap corruption error on the frist free.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "czmq.h"
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

zctx_t *zmq_ctx=NULL;

void normalizer() 
{
    void *xmitter;
    xmitter = zsocket_new(zmq_ctx, ZMQ_PAIR);
    zsocket_connect (xmitter, "inproc://sender");
    while(1)
    {
        zstr_send (xmitter, "hello");
    }
    zsocket_destroy (zmq_ctx, xmitter);
}

void sender() 
{
    void *receiver = zsocket_new(zmq_ctx, ZMQ_PAIR);
    int rc = zsocket_bind (receiver, "inproc://sender");
    boost::thread t(&normalizer);
    int counter=0;
    while(1)
    {
        char *string = zstr_recv (receiver);
        counter++;
        if(counter%10000==0)
        {
            std::cout << "counter: " << counter << std::endl;
        }
        //free (string); //problem is here
    }
    zsocket_destroy(zmq_ctx, receiver);
}

void main(void)
{
    zmq_ctx = zctx_new();
    boost::thread t(&sender);
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: I suggest `zstr_free (char **string_p)` is probably what you're looking for. [Perhaps check that in the docs](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zstr). The leak is in *your* code; not zeromq.

Comment: zstr_free is introduced in czmq ver. 2.1.0. I'm using 2.0.1. 
Anyway This problem vanishes if I use static library of czmq. It only occurs in case when CZMQ is built as shared library (DLL).

Comment: And you built the Windows DLL, so I have to assume everyone is playing with the same CRT expectations and such. Sry I'm not familiar with the older API.